# Permissions in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, permissions

I have created 10 database of 'Northwind' for training purpose. Suppose I have 10 students, so databases are Northwind_Student1,Northwind_Student2 etc. I would like to create separate login for each pupil, so that Student1 can only see(or can access) the data base 'Northwind_Student1'. How can I accomplish this using T-SQL or SSMS 2008 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS, expand the `Security` tree of the server in Object Explorer and right-click `Logins` to choose `New Login...`, then add as many as needed.

Then in the `Security` tree of each *individual database*, add the login as a user of that db and grant appropriate rights.

Answer (score 2):

You can create different users for different databases and assign permissions like below. It's for SQL 2008, but it will be same for 2005 also :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create 10 different logins and assign each to the database it can access.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE LOGIN yourloginname WITH PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!